# How to test a GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: testing, gitlab-ci

We use GitLab CI/CD on a private GitLab server and maintain a quite complex gitlab-ci.yaml with includes and rules:

- Some pipeline jobs only run on specific branches
- Some pipeline jobs only run when specific variables are set
- Some pipeline jobs are taken from the include without changes
- Some pipeline jobs are taken from the include, but overwritten in the current file
- etc.

Currently, our quality assurance steps are:

- Using the GitLab API to lint the file
- Building, testing and deploying a test project to test the pipeline roughly (smoke tests)

What we would like to add are unit tests where we can test the behaviour of the pipeline under specific conditions (specific branches, variables, other conditions) so we can ensure that specific settings lead to a specific pipeline configuration. Unfortunately, I was not able to find any information on how to properly test GitLab CI pipelines. How can we do that?

Comment: We are in the same boat and looking for tools / procedures here. Did you get anywhere with your question?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pipeline Editor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html) can provide some of what you're looking for, but at time of writing (v16.2) there's still no good way to *simulate* pipelines for anything except the default branch.

In addition to basic linting, some new features that are available since this question was asked:

[Simulate a CICD Pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#simulate-a-cicd-pipeline) (against the default branch) *Added in 15.3*

> A pipeline simulation can help find problems such as incorrect rules and needs job dependencies

[View Included CICD Configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#view-included-cicd-configuration) *Added in 15.0 via feature flag. Flag removed in 15.1*

> see a list of all included [via the `include` keyword]
> configuration files

[Visualize CI configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#visualize-ci-configuration) *Added in 13.5 via feature flag. Flag removed in 13.12*

> The visualization shows all stages and jobs. Any `needs` relationships are displayed as lines connecting jobs together, showing the hierarchy of execution.

[View full configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/index.html#view-full-configuration) *Added in 13.9 via feature flag. Flag removed in 13.12*

> show expanded YAML configuration where:
>
> - Configuration imported with include is copied into the view.
> - Jobs that use extends display with the extended configuration merged into the job.
> - YAML anchors are replaced with the linked configuration.
> - YAML !reference tags are also replaced with the linked configuration.